# Bar grows the wrong direction in Barplot using R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a barplot (using R) with data growing from -12 upwards to -5. I tried many things but with no success. Here what I tried, but the bar plot always tend to grow from zero. Very odd! Please help.

```
RN <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
Exp <- c(-7, -8, -9, -10, -10, -7)
Model <- c(-6, -7, -8, -10, -8, -6)

dim <- list(c('Exp','Model'), RN)

mydata = matrix(c(Exp , Model), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = dim)
mydata

barplot(mydata, beside=TRUE, ylim=c(-12,-5), space = c(0.1 , 0.9))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to do this *directly* via `barplot` (of course, you can always construct it yourself from scratch). But here's one option using **ggplot2**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(mydata)

ggplot(dat,aes(x = Var2,y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1),position = "dodge",stat = "identity") + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-4.75,-10.25))
```

[image]

FYI: One possible reason why this isn't straightforward in `barplot` is that truncated axes like these are frequently considered a Bad Thing among data visualization experts (it can create misleadingly large differences between quantities, since you've artificially altered the scale), who also happen to be the sorts of people likely to be writing tools like the code for `barplot`, so it might not occur to them that this is something worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but please don't do it unless you have an excellent reason (and I can't think of any possible reason which would be):

```
offset <- 5
barplot(-mydata-offset, beside=TRUE, ylim=c(5,12), 
        space = c(0.1 , 0.9), offset=offset, axes=FALSE)
axis(2, at=5:12, labels=-12:-5)
```

[image]

It's misleading and in general makes a terrible graph. You're better off leaving  the negative values and original graphs.